# Damping on a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators

So I have this question where you are given a simple pendulum, and you are asked how increasing the damping will affect the frequency and amplitude, I am at a loss as the answer says that frequency is unchanged, however, I was taught the relationship $T \propto \sqrt{m} $  thus $ f \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ Im told that the period is changed due to damping so shouldn't frequency change too?

I may have a completely wrong understanding here, if so could you enlighten me on how and why damping affects Period and supposedly Frequency?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator)? Typically a damped pendulum will have a lower frequency than an undamped one.

Comment: Thats what I dont understand, the answer says a damped pendulum will not have its frequency changed, despite its period increasing.

Comment: If the period increases the frequency **must** decrease.  They are reciprocals plain and simple.

Comment: My example uses a simple pendulum that has been damped, and they say that frequency is unaffected and I just don't understand why, I am under the assumption that the period increases the frequency decreases, however the book says frequency is unchanged on a damped system? So I guess I can say the answer is wrong.

Comment: Where did you get your formulas from? They are not the correct ones to use for a simple pendulum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your formulation if you believe that the frequency changes or not. Neither what is the answer in the book.
Now, the answer may depended on what type of oscillator you have. If it's a forced (driven) oscillator, the damping affects the amplitude but not the frequency. The frequency will be that of the driving force.
If you have a free oscillator with damping, the frequency will be decreased by damping (when compared with the value without damping).